# How to connect textfield with function of open_button class

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

Currently, I learn Java guI, swing.
I would like to link the j1('open' button) in Yam class with a Open_Button Class's function.
If I write a file name in "textField" which is a global variable in Yam class, and press the 'open', the "TextArea" has to show an output the opened file's content. 
but somehow it doesn't work. I think the open_button class's function is not connected with the "textField" in Yam class. 
But I really can't find what's wrong. 
(sorry for my poor Engish..;( i'll show you full code. I want to follow Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable rull but I really don't know where is wrong part..)

```
 Yam class )

   import javax.swing.*;
   import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;
   import java.io.File.*;
   import java.io.*;
   import java.nio.file.*;

   public class Yam extends JFrame {
   Container contentPane;
   JButton j1, j2, j3, j4, j5, j6;
   JTextField textField;
   JTextField textField_1; 
   TextArea textArea, textArea_1;

  public Yam() {
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  contentPane = getContentPane();
  contentPane.setLayout(null);

  textField = new JTextField();
  textField.setBounds(14, 12, 240, 24);
  contentPane.add(textField);
  textField.setColumns(20);

  j1 = new JButton("Open");
  j1.setBounds(294, 11, 105, 27);
  j1.addActionListener(new AB());
  contentPane.add(j1);

  textField_1 = new JTextField();
  textField_1.setBounds(14, 48, 240, 24);
  contentPane.add(textField_1);
  textField_1.setColumns(20);

  j2 = new JButton("Save");
  j2.setBounds(294, 47, 105, 27);
  contentPane.add(j2); 

  textArea = new TextArea();
  textArea.setBounds(10, 105, 405, 190);
  contentPane.add(textArea);

  j3 = new JButton("Compile");
  j3.setBounds(10, 319, 87, 25);
  j3.addActionListener(new AB());
  contentPane.add(j3);

  j4 = new JButton("Save Errors");
  j4.setBounds(111, 319, 87, 25);
  contentPane.add(j4);

  j5 = new JButton("Delete");
  j5.setBounds(217, 319, 87, 25);
  contentPane.add(j5);

  j6 = new JButton("Clear");
  j6.setBounds(321, 319, 87, 25);
  j6.addActionListener(new AB());
  contentPane.add(j6);

  textArea_1 = new TextArea();
  textArea_1.setBounds(10, 391, 405, 253);
  contentPane.add(textArea_1);

  setSize(506, 698);
  setVisible(true); }



 class AB implements ActionListener {
 private TextArea args;

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  Object source = e.getSource();
  CmdClass cmd = new CmdClass();
  Open_button open = new Open_button();
  JFrame f = new JFrame("what");

     if(source == j1) {
             }
     else if(source == j2) {
         }

     else if(source == j3) { 
        if(cmd.main(args))
           textArea_1.append("Compile Success\n");
     }
     else if(source == j4) { }
     else if(source == j5) { }
     else {
        textField.setText(" ");
        textField_1.setText(" ");
        textArea.setText(" ");
        textArea_1.setText(" "); }}}



     public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Yam();
       }




       public static String getFileName() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;}}
```

---

```
     Open_button class)

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.File;

public class Open_button {
    Path Path;

    public void main(String Str_paths){
        Yam y = new Yam();

        Str_paths = y.textField.getText();
        Path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(Str_paths);
        File file = Path.toFile();

        if(Path.toFile() != null)
            y.textArea.append("file exist!");       
        else {
            y.textArea_1.append("file not exist");  
            BufferedReader br = null;
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Str_paths));
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    y.textArea.append(line);
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "link a JTextField and a JButton" ?? from within the actionperformed, just call a field.getText or something similar

Comment: You need to post a valid [mcve] for us to see how things are hooked together. Likely the problem is one of your using wrong references, again not hooking your up your two classes correctly, but it's hard to tell from this post. Again, improve the code so that we can compile and run it by creating the MCVE (please read the [mcve] link for more).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want for some reason to open and read a file which the filepath is designated on the jtextfield; Simplest way would be:

```
JButton openButton = new JButton("Open File");              
openButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         String thePath = textfield.getText();
         File theFile = new File(thePath);
         ...read..write..
     }
});
```

I would declare this directly on the Yam class;

From what I have seen, your code has two issues: first, there are two Yam (y) instances (the one declared in OpenButton class is different than the one located above) and, second, you assume that the file is readable and always located on Filesystem view...I think you should also consider a JFileChooser dialog.
Regards, André